# jQuery Slidedown - I search another effect but don't know the name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a HTML version of the Office Ribbon to implement it in any HTML website.
Currently everything is working fine. I do have a button and when I click on it, a menu is shown.

This is done by using the jQuery SlideDown function:

```
$(this).slideDown({
    duration: time
});
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/qwV84/

Now, when you open the fiddle and you click the "new items" icon, you see that a menu is rendered (it's slowed down just for showing you). And I do have a problem with the rendering of the menu. The top of the menu is rendered and than it goes to the bottom.

When you have Office 2013 installed open Outlook and click an icon to open a menu there. There the bottom of the menu is rendered just under the icon and then the menu is falling down and the top is being rendered. In fact, it looks like the menu is dropping down from behind an invisble white panel.

I would like to achieve the same effect but I don't know how. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: That code is a huge mess. Cut it down to the relevant parts.

Comment: jQueryUI calls what you describe the `Slide` effect. And what jQuery's `slideDown` method does is called `Blind` in jQuery UI. I don't think jQuery has a  built-in equivalent of jQuery UI's `Slide` effect, although there are probably a thousand plugins that implement it.

Comment: So, I've updated the jsFiddle so the mess is removed. Here's a slimmed down version: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/qwV84/1/

Comment: Thanks Frank, that was really the solutions that I needed.